# notepad++ как сделать замену на следующей строке от искомого значения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

День добрый! Подскажите как сделать замену значения в следующей строке от искомого значения:

```
M106  S10
G01 X9.8 Y0.0 F280
M106  S0
G01 X12.4 Y0.0 F280
M106  S10
G01 X12.5 Y0.0 F280
M106  S0
G01 X12.6 Y0.0 F280
```

Нужно найти все строки где есть значение S0 и уже в следующей строке в конце поменять значение F280 на F5000

Comment: Если вам надо регулярное выражение, то поставьте метку [tag:регулярные-выражения] и приведите однозначное описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найденное этим (PCRE):

```
S0[\s\S]+?\KF280
```

заменить этим:

```
F5000
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5a32p

Answer (score 1):

Заменить

```
(S0.*\r?\n.*\b)F280$
```

на

```
$1F5000
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Тоже пишет совпадений не найдено

Comment: @user402695 скриншот же привели, где написано, что замены есть